# debug mysqli query with or die mysqli_error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I don't know what is wrong.

```
$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO post_items(`post_id`,`content`,`date`,`user_id`,`category_id`) 
    VALUES ('".$postid.", '".$content."', '".$date."', '".$user_id."', '".$category_id."')");
if($result) { 
    echo "hey";
}
```

How can I use `mysqli_error` function to check the cause of error? The syntax of PHP is just fine I think. I guess it has problem with my database.

Comment: ...`else echo $db->error;`   The MySQLi connection object `$db` has an `error` property.

Comment: You really ought to start learning about [MySQLi prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to improve the security of your queries, and eliminate the potential quoting problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with single quotes. You have a `'` just before your `$postid`, but not one after. This means that the SQL query will be seeing `'$postid, '` as your first variable and then being confused about the remained.

Try changing your SQL to read:

```
$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO post_items(`post_id`,`content`,`date`,`user_id`,`category_id`) 
VALUES ('".$postid."', '".$content."', '".$date."', '".$user_id."', '".$category_id."')");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I agree with Michael Berkowski though, you should look at using MySQLi or POD to prepare statements. It removes some of the possibility of errors and would improve the security.